# Student's report

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I need a student's mark report.

```
I have the following tables: 
- user table with: user_id, first name, last name, course_id
- a course table with: course_id, name
- a subject table with: subject_id, course_id, name
- a marks table with: mark, subject_id, course_id, user_id
```

I need to show all students from a selected course with all their marks for all their subjects.

For example: course_id = 18

```
Last Name | Name | Math | Geography | Science | Physics
Doe       | John |  8   |     7     |    4    |    7
Doe       | Jane |  5   |     8     |    4    |    6
```

and so on until the last student ordered alphabetically using last name.

Is possible to achieve using SQL? No need php nor anything.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you include the query or code which you have tried ?

Comment: Yes, but consider handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: Also, it seems you need a `pivot` fnctionality to show those values in a variable number of columns, and MariaDB doesn't have pivot (as far as I know). You'll need to receive a list of lists.

Comment: How do I "receive a list of lists"? You mean to create a temp table or something? I basically need to export that report to Excel/Pdf once twice a year

Answer (score -1):

select u.last_name , u.first_name , s.name,m.mark

from user u , subject s , marks m

where u.user_id = m.user_id and s.subject_id = m.subject_id and s.course_id = m.course_id and s.course_id = 18 order by u.last_name asc

This query is for course id 18 only however u can have for all course_id.

This query will not produce the result int the format u mentioned but it will have a separate row for each subject a student has enrolled.

Hope this may help.

Comment: It's something.. but it won't show subjects name at the header. I mean, you show the marks but don't know for which subject each one. Right?

Comment: subject name is also shown by s.name . ya on header definitely it wont show

Comment: I had the time to execute it in my db and it shows all the records from all students in a "vertical" way rather than horizontal as expected (each subject next to each other and 1 row per student). Any way to accomplish it?